# Checking other 'Tiles/Walls' around other tiles in a city building type game. Like 'Rimworld'

Tags: java, logic, libgdx

I've been trying to figure out a way to do a city/colony building type game, where everything gets placed and built by the player, for example every wall, like the way 'Rimworld' does it.

Now the only problem I am having, is the placing of every piece of wall. I've been trying to find a good way for the walls, when they finish getting created/built, they check the other walls around them, and then change the way they look, depending on what the other wall is.

So if I place a row of walls:

O O O O O

then place another row of walls underneath them like this:

O O O O O

O

O

O

I want it to automatically change the wall in the corner, to a corner piece, and the other pieces into the direction they are meant to go. Like the way facing 'Down'

I hope you understand what I am tying to say.

I have been trying to think of a good way to go about this. One way was looping through a List which contains each wall, then loop through again, and check the walls, around the wall being checked. But if i had say, 1000 walls, then that would be really really slow, checking each wall 1000 times, and doesn't seem like a good way to do this.

If it helps, I am using Libgdx/Java.

I don't need code, only pseudocode, or an explanation of the best way to do this, but code would be helpful.

**--------EDIT------------**

if anyone is interested, I solved my own problem by using this below: It's not the best way, but it works. If there is a better way to do this, with the way I have done (it's a bit long, so many if statements) please share.

What happens is you put in the x and y of the tile you want to check, and everything is based upon that. It all works the way I want it too, but seems a bit messy. How would I go about cleaning this code up?

```
public void checkWallType(int x, int y) {
    boolean wallAtTop = false;
    boolean wallAtRight = false;
    boolean wallAtBottom = false;
    boolean wallAtLeft = false;

    if (tileMap[x][y - 1] != null) {
        if (tileMap[x][y - 1].type == "Wall") {
            wallAtTop = true;
        }
    }
    if (tileMap[x + 1][y] != null) {
        if (tileMap[x + 1][y].type == "Wall") {
            wallAtRight = true;
        }
    }
    if (tileMap[x][y + 1] != null) {
        if (tileMap[x][y + 1].type == "Wall") {
            wallAtBottom = true;
        }
    }
    if (tileMap[x - 1][y] != null) {
        if (tileMap[x - 1][y].type == "Wall") {
            wallAtLeft = true;
        }
    }


    if (wallAtTop && wallAtRight == false && wallAtBottom == false && wallAtLeft == false) {
        tileMap[x][y].wallType = "BottomEnd";
    }
    else if (wallAtTop == false && wallAtRight && wallAtBottom == false && wallAtLeft == false) {
        tileMap[x][y].wallType = "LeftEnd";
    }
    else if (wallAtTop == false && wallAtRight == false && wallAtBottom && wallAtLeft == false) {
        tileMap[x][y].wallType = "TopEnd";
    }
    else if (wallAtTop == false && wallAtRight == false && wallAtBottom == false && wallAtLeft) {
        tileMap[x][y].wallType = "RightEnd";
    }

    else if (wallAtTop && wallAtRight == false && wallAtBottom && wallAtLeft == false) {
        tileMap[x][y].wallType = "TopBottom";
    }
    else if (wallAtTop == false && wallAtRight && wallAtBottom == false && wallAtLeft) {
        tileMap[x][y].wallType = "LeftRight";
    }

    else if (wallAtTop && wallAtRight && wallAtBottom == false && wallAtLeft == false) {
        tileMap[x][y].wallType = "BottomLeft";
    }
    else if (wallAtTop == false && wallAtRight && wallAtBottom && wallAtLeft == false) {
        tileMap[x][y].wallType = "LeftTop";
    }
    else if (wallAtTop == false && wallAtRight == false && wallAtBottom && wallAtLeft) {
        tileMap[x][y].wallType = "TopRight";
    }
    else if (wallAtTop && wallAtRight == false && wallAtBottom == false && wallAtLeft) {
        tileMap[x][y].wallType = "BottomRight";
    }

    else if (wallAtTop && wallAtRight && wallAtBottom && wallAtLeft == false) {
        tileMap[x][y].wallType = "TopRightBottom";
    }
    else if (wallAtTop == false && wallAtRight && wallAtBottom && wallAtLeft) {
        tileMap[x][y].wallType = "RightBottomLeft";
    }
    else if (wallAtTop && wallAtRight == false && wallAtBottom && wallAtLeft) {
        tileMap[x][y].wallType = "BottomLeftTop";
    }
    else if (wallAtTop && wallAtRight && wallAtBottom == false && wallAtLeft) {
        tileMap[x][y].wallType = "LeftTopRight";
    }

    else if (wallAtTop && wallAtRight && wallAtBottom && wallAtLeft) {
        tileMap[x][y].wallType = "Open";
    }
}
```

Comment: Every `Tile` could store its neighbors as a reference. So every `Tile` would have 4 or 8 neighbors (diagonal neighbors?). Then you only need to check 4/8 walls for each wall/tile.

Answer (score 1):

How many different tiles do you have / need to represent a wall? In case those are not too many, the number of rules (when to show which wall) should be small as well. So lets assume you have:

- one tile for walls aligned horizontally, having no buddies to their top or bottom
- one tile for walls aligned vertically, having no buddies to their left or right
- four different tiles for walls having buddies to their (right, bottom), (left, bottom), (right, top) and (left, top)

This is just an example. Those 6 rules are mutual exclusive, which means only one of them will match. To decide which of the rules to apply, just create a [Chain-Of-Responsibility](http://www.oodesign.com/chain-of-responsibility-pattern.html) where each `Handler` is one of those rules. The rules need to know for which wall to find the right tile. Hence you have to pass in the map itself and the location of the wall for which to find the proper tile. Now each rule in the chain check if it matches. If so, the rule return the tile. Otherwise the rule passes the input parameters along the chain. If no rule matches, the `standard` wall tile is appropriate.

You may apply the rules as soon as the player drops a wall, or you post-process the whole map at the end. Delaying the processing requires to either inspect each location of the map, or to remember wall locations. I would suggest to do it just in time. This way you have to process only the dropped wall and all its adjacent walls, which is more efficient and much more responsive for the player.

Hope my suggestion may help you. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to check all 1000 walls? If you have tiles, you have coordinates. And if you habe coordinates, you can just check what's on the tiles of x-1|y, x+1|y, x|y-1 and x|y+1.